# Rails form called from a another controller's action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have models `User`, `Event`, `Rsvp`.  I want to have a `Rsvp` form appear in the `show` page of my `Event` model.  A User can create many Events but I don't need to know which User create which Event (at least I don't think).  A User can also rsvp to an Event. My models looks like so:

**user.rb**

```
has_many :rsvps
```

**event.rb**

```
has_many :rsvps
```

**rsvp.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :event
```

I think my RsvpsController should look like this:

```
class RsvpsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = current_user
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @rsvp = Rsvp.new
  end
end
```

Now in my `show` page of an `Event` I want a form in the sidebar which lets `Users` rsvp to the `Event`.  I have something like this but it's not quite right.  I'm especially not sure what is the first argument that goes into form_for:

```
form_for [@user, @event, @rsvp], url: {controller: 'rsvps_controller', action: 'create' } do |f|
```

in my events/show.html.haml I try to render the Rsvp new action like this:

```
=render template: 'rsvps/new'
```

but this instead renders an event/new partial

**EDIT**
I think I know why this render is rendering an Event new partial.  Inside Rsvps/new.html.haml I have `render 'form'`.  I also have a _form.html.haml in my Events folder.

**EDIT2**

**rsvps_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @rsvp = current_user.rsvps.build(params[:rsvp])
  if @rsvp.save
    flash[:success] = "You have RSVPed."
    redirect_to Event.find(params[:event_id])
  else

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you want to create the reservation for the current user, you should only pass the event to the rsvp create action. for the form, use

```
<%= form_for Rsvp.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :event_id, value: @event.id %>
```

This should give you access to the event that the current user wants to rsvp.  So in your create action of the Rsvp controller, you can build the reservation by using the following code

```
def create
  @rsvp = current_user.rsvps.build params[:rsvp]

  if @rsvp.save
    ...
end
```

Comment: almost there @jvnill. Couple quick questions.  See my EDIT2 above.  Would that be the "correct" Rails way to redirect back to the same event?  And also, what would I put in between the else and the end, I want to re-render Event's show template with an error if the form isn't filled out correctly.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out: render 'events/show'.  Thanks for the help!